# Naming convention on expansions for an external company's web service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Right now I am creating an expansion to an existing web service that a company is offering to the public. Let say that the company is named "Autodealer". Their package name would then be something like:
`com.autodealer.api` for their API.

I am creating an extension of this API that I will offer for the public as well as the source code on Github. My question is what to name the packages in my Java project? I can't use their package name I guess.

Should I use my own company's name and add their company name to it like this:

`com.mycompany.theircompany` and then start organizing the code under that? What is usual practise? It is a Java REST API if that matter.

Comment: Read this: http://central.sonatype.org/pages/choosing-your-coordinates.html.

Comment: That answers almost all my questions. However when I push my code to Github now I have used my own group id and I created an artifact id. What happens if the company that I built the extension to fork the repository and start adding changes to it. Then they probably wants to have the artifact published under their group id. Is that correct?

Comment: Well it theirs problem then. :)

Comment: Just a note: Maybe it is better to check with this company before you start to develop something.

Comment: I could, but it is already done:) Anyway it was a question on a general basis. I just used this as an example.